# R2DBC Return Type @Query

Tags: mysql, spring, database, kotlin, spring-data-r2dbc

I would like to be able to insert a value into a table into r2dbc using the `@Query` designation (as opposed to the built in `save` function. However I don't know what the return type is for the SQL statement. I've tried `String`, `Book`, `List<Book>` `Unit`, and `Void`.

I have two types of errors. When I try and use a `Book` return value (assuming that the SQL statement will return the value of the inserted row) I get -

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
```

If  I attempt to use a string I get the following. Apparently `String` return types are not compatible with `r2dbc`. There is a springboot persistable package (`import org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable`) which I've attempted to return a `Persistable<String>`, but that has not worked.

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException:
 Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.String!
```

**What I think is happening** is that what is being returned is attempting to write to an index of some type that is neither a `Book` value, `String`, or some nullable type - ie the SQL message that is returned in a standard mysql interface `OK, 1 row inserted into Books`or some such. I don't care about the insert value, but I can't call the function without knowing what that is so I can assign a type.

Here is what I have so far. **Another question** that came up while I've been working on this - is it possible to call a functions return type? I found this abstract class definition here `https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-callable/return-type.html` but no pragmatic examples so far. Thanks for the help~

```
package platypus.bookstore.repos.books

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.kotlin.CoroutineCrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.Query  
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param 
import platypus.bookstore.classes.db.books.Books
import platypus.bookstore.classes.general.ResultString
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository

@Repository
interface BookRepository : CoroutineCrudRepository<Books, Long> {
    @Query("""
    INSERT INTO BOOKS (title, subtitle, publisher, currentcopyright, authorbio, synopsis, isbn) 
    values (:title, :subtitle, :publisher, :currentcopyright, :authorbio, :synopsis, :isbn);
    """)
    suspend fun addBook(title: String, subtitle: String, publisher: String, 
    currentcopyright: String, authorbio: String, synopsis: String, isbn: String
    ):???RETURNTYPE???

    @Query("""
      select * from books
    """)
    suspend fun findBooks():List<Books>
}
```

EDIT - I have a working implementation with a save function which I've now confirmed, so this isn't a *huge* deal. But...I think that this should be looked into and either fixed or more documentation available. I don't like having to rely on "magic" in order to make a simple SQL query into a database. Thanks!

SOLVED! - Thanks to Mark over at the spring-data-r2dbc github (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/618#event-4981291976) this issue has been solved. Here is the implementation for anyone that encounters a similar issue.

Basically you just have to use the @Modifying tag to write raw SQL -

Calling from the controller -

```
  suspend fun addBook(book: Books):List<Books>{
    println("addBooks")
    // bookRepo.save(book);
    bookRepo.saveabook(
      book.title, book.subtitle, book.publisher, 
      book.currentcopyright, book.bookedition, 
      book.uniqueid, book.authorbio, book.synopsis, book.isbn
    )
    var bookList:List<Books> = findBooks()
    return bookList;
  }
```

Inside the repository -

```
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.Query  
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.Modifying

@Repository
interface BookRepository : CoroutineCrudRepository<Books, Long> {
    

    // The result of a modifying query can be:
    // Void (or Kotlin Unit) to discard update count and await completion.
    // Integer or another numeric type emitting the affected rows count.
    // Boolean to emit whether at least one row was updated.

    @Modifying
    @Query(
    """
      insert into books (title, subtitle, publisher, currentcopyright, bookedition, uniqueid, authorbio, synopsis, isbn) values (:title, :subtitle, :publisher, :currentcopyright, :bookedition, :uniqueid, :authorbio, :synopsis, :isbn)
    """)
    suspend fun saveabook(title:String, subtitle:String, publisher:String, currentcopyright:String, bookedition:String, uniqueid:String, authorbio:String, synopsis:String, isbn:String):Void

    @Query("""
      select * from books
    """)
    suspend fun findBooks():List<Books>
}
```